# Meaning of “qu'il était” in a sentence

Tags: sens, subordonnées

I am having hard times translating this sentence

> Les anciens domestiques de la maison soupçonnaient qu'il était fils de la soeur de monsieur le baron et d'un bon et
>   honnête gentilhomme du voisinage, que cette demoiselle ne voulut jamais épouser parce qu'il n'avait pu
>   prouver que soixante et onze quartiers, et que le reste de son arbre généalogique avait été perdu par l'injure du
>   temps.

What bothers me, is

> **qu'il était** fils de la soeur

I understand that the baron's sister's son is suspected of something by service staff. But what does ***qu'il était*** indicate? Is this merely to emphasize the affiliation of said son? I am bamboozled by the imperfect indicative of *être* at this position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interprétation:

> the baron's sister's son is suspected of something by service staff

is wrong, the sentence is better translated to:

> The service staff guess that he was the baron's sister's son.

Comment: So one could say that "qu'il êtait" loosely translates to "that he he is"?

Comment: @Sprottenwels: Yes but it is "imparfait": `that he was`

Comment: Actually I'm not sure but I think the French text is wrong and should rather be "soupçonnaient qu'il fut" or "soupçonnaient qu'il soit"

Comment: @Bartdude: The french text is definitely correct.

Answer (score -2):

in a simple way It's mean litteraly "who was"